# Как удалить определенный div блок и его содержимое из строки

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Использую библиотеку `PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser` для парсинга страницы.

На странице есть *div* блоки которые хотелось удалить вместе с их содержимым.
Эти блоки имеют такой вид:

```
<div data-js2="banner-click">
   содержимое
</div>
```

Но так же эти блоки могут иметь и такой вид:

```
<div class="любой_класс" data-js2="banner-click">
   содержимое
</div>
```

Для парсинга всего содержимого делаю так:

```
$text = $article->find('.content');
```

Как удалить ненужные div и их содержимое?

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

выбрать блоки и заменить `outertext` на пустую строку

```
foreach($article->find("[data-js2=banner-click]") as $b){
    $b->outertext = "";
}
```